# html within label elements

Tags: html, label

Is it possible to include html elements - such as img, span or div - within a label element?

In my page, I have radio buttons allowing users to choose between different layouts, and I'd like to display a visual label rather than plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL), the `label` element may contain “inline elements”, which includes `img` and `span` but excludes `div`. This however is too permissive, and [HTML5 PR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) says: “Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element's labeled control, and no descendant `label` elements.” Here “phrasing content” is largely the same as “inline elements”.

On the practical side, it is safest to omit all interactive content, such as links. Although the effects are in principle well-defined, it is poor usability to have content that acts in different ways, e.g. so that clicking on a link inside a label causes the link to be followed by clicking elsewhere in the label focuses on the associated form field (and possibly toggles its setting).

But there is no problem with using images inside a label, as far as element nesting goes. For accessibility, the image should have an `alt` text *or* the rest of the label should make it understandable even when the image is not seen. And you can use `span` to style part of the label different from the rest.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label, phrasing content tags are allowed inside a label element. That list includes img and span tags but not divs. For the full list of phrasing content tags, check out the reference at mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content

Comment: +1 I marked Jukka's reply as the most complete answer, but yours is definitely helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use anything inside a label tag.

Comment: Thanks, any link as reference and to confirm browser support?